# Не работает транзакция между фрагментами android studio java

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

Есть два фрагмента. В одном установлен EditText, в другом Textview. Нужно передать имя с одного фрагмента на другой. Много чего перепробовал. От сохранения переменных разного уровня сохранности, до транзакций между фрагментами. Ничего не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Код первого фрагмента:

'''

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentFirstBinding binding;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

'''

его xml:

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/editTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.36" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editTextPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_first"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_first"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

'''

Код второго фрагмента:

'''

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSecondBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentSecondBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_ThirdFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

'''

Его xml:

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_second"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_second" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

'''

Остальное (MainActivity, nav_host_fragment, activity_main, content_main и прочее скину при необходимости). Надеюсь на оперативную помощь. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передать данные требуется при навигации из фрагмента_1 во фрагмент_2?

Тогда прицепите их `action`-у навигации:

```java
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("argument_key", "yourStringValue");
NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment, bundle);
```

И добавьте в соответствующий action в navigation.xml:

```xml
<argument android:name="argument_key"
    app:argType="string"
    android:defaultValue=""/>
```

А в целевом фрагменте ловите их:

```
private int getPlaceIdArgument() {
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
return arguments == null
    ? ""
    : arguments.getString("argument_key");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! 
Все понятно, кроме отлова в целевом фрагменте... Как отловить отправленное сообщение во втором фрагменте? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Я же написал Вам: ```private int getPlaceIdArgument() {
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
return arguments == null
    ? ""
    : arguments.getString("argument_key");
}```  вот метод во фрагменте вернет переданное значение

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: В таком случае принято отмечать ответ как верный